# RDF - More than one Object for one Subject-Property

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I've got one (maybe) simple question: Can I assign more than one ObjectResource to a fixed Subject-Property Statement?

I want my RDF-Triples look like that:

```
[http://somewhere/Angela_Merkel, http://somewhere/properties#isMentionedIn, http://somewhere/New_York_Times]

[http://somewhere/Angela_Merkel, http://somewhere/properties#isMentionedIn, http://somewhere/The_Guardian]

[http://somewhere/Angela_Merkel, http://somewhere/properties#isMentionedIn, http://somewhere/BildZeitung]
```

and so on.. Is this rdf well-formed?

And can I implement this in Apache Jena?

Comment: The format that you've got is actually very close to N-Triples already.  Writing as `<http://somewhere/Angela_Merkel> <http://somewhere/properties#isMentionedIn> <http://somewhere/New_York_Times> .` you'd have legal N-Triples format, and you could actually test whether the RDF can be loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this would be well formed data and it is a common way to define multiple values for a given property on a given subject.

RDF has very few restrictions on what triples you can declare. Essentially these boil down to the following:

- The subject must be a IRI/blank node
- The predicate must be a IRI
- The object may be a IRI/blank node/literal
- Duplicate triples are ignored i.e. Declaring the same triple multiple times is the same as declaring it once

IRIs are a superset of URIs - see [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) for more details.  TL;DR IRIs are basically URIs with a wider permitted character set to allow internationalised identifiers

Beyond that you are free to declare as many triples as you want.

You can certainly implement this with Apache Jena, I would suggest starting with the [Introduction Tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html) and asking new more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah, i looked through some Introductions, but i became a little nervous, so i asked. Cheers, FFoDWindow.

Comment: [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/) says IRI instead of URI. The space of possible IRIs is a superset of the space of possible URIs.