# In RDF can subject have two identical (same URI) predicates?

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

For a given subject, can two statements be made whose predicates are identical?

For example, can both the statements on line 2 and 3 co-exist?

```
data:myDataPoint1234 a abc:GeoPoint ;
  abc:isIdentifiedBy data:lat20 ;
  abc:isIdentifiedBy data:lon150 .

data:lat20 a abc:Latitude ;
  abc:representationValue "20"^^xsd:string .

data:lon150 a abc:Longitude ;
  abc:representationValue "150"^^xsd:string .
```

UPDATE: Duplicate question: [RDF - More than one Object for one Subject-Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505700/rdf-more-than-one-object-for-one-subject-property)

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra RDF4J doesn't seem to want to let us add a second statement about the subject if the predicate is the same.

Comment: RDF4J (and any RDF tool) definitely does allow that, so something else must be going wrong. Can you [edit] your question to show what you're trying to do, the result you are getting and the result you were expecting?

Comment: why should it not be possible? Without how could anybody work with multi-valued properties? Show the RDF4J code please

Comment: @JeenBroekstra  & uninformeduser: Thanks for the answer. Agreed it should be possible. I had someone else in my team having trouble with RDF4J so was really just asking the question in principle.

Comment: @Lisa if your team member has any more problems with RDF4J, tell them to reach out on one of the RDF4J support forums.

Comment: Apologies. Realised this is a duplicate question, but was hard to find via search so useful to keep this as a placeholder for search engine. Happy to close as dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely permitted.

Verified by validating the posted Turtle example at http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/convert

Double-checked by outputing to XML format and validating using the official W3C converter at https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/rdfval

Both parsers accepted the example.

Resulting statements from the W3C parser:

> Triples of the Data Model
> Number  Subject Predicate   Object
> 1   http://abc.blah.com isIdentifiedBy  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AnnotationProperty
> 2   http://abc.blah.com representationValue http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AnnotationProperty
> 3   http://abc.blah.com GeoPoint    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class
> 4   http://abc.blah.com Latitude    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class
> 5   http://abc.blah.com Longitude   http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class
> 6   http://data.blah.com lat20  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual
> 7   http://data.blah.com lat20  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://abc.blah.comLatitude
> 8   http://data.blah.com lat20  http://abc.blah.comrepresentationValue  "20"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
> 9   http://data.blah.com lon150 http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual
> 10  http://data.blah.com lon150 http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://abc.blah.comLongitude
> 11  http://data.blah.com lon150 http://abc.blah.comrepresentationValue  "150"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
> 12  http://data.blah.com myDataPoint1234    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual
> 13  http://data.blah.com myDataPoint1234    http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://abc.blah.comGeoPoint
> 14  http://data.blah.com myDataPoint1234    http://abc.blah.comisIdentifiedBy   http://data.blah.com lat20
> 15  http://data.blah.commyDataPoint1234 http://abc.blah.comisIdentifiedBy   http://data.blah.com lon150